# Can lock-free inter-thread communication be implemented non-atomic?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, lock-free

The problem is that I have two threads. One thread only sets some request flags, and the other thread resets the request flags. **Hence both threads have write access to the flags.** I'm trying to do this without synchronization.

Here is what I've implemented, and I can't perceive how it might go wrong.

```
volatile uint32_t      g_FORM_Requests;



#define FORM_REQUEST(X)                                                       \
do {                                                                          \
  if (g_FORM_Requests)                                                        \
  {                                                                           \
    g_SHELL_Print("Server is busy executing previous requests...");           \
  }                                                                           \
  else                                                                        \
  {                                                                           \
    g_FORM_Requests=(X);                                                      \
  }                                                                           \
} while (0x00U)



void * SERVER_Thread( void * Data)
{
  uint32_t      Snapshot;

  while (!Done)
  {
    /*   Take a snapshot of requests. */
    Snapshot=g_FORM_Requests;
    Execute(Snapshot);
    g_FORM_Requests ^= Snapshot;
  }

  return (NULL);
}
```

The form issues requests to `SERVER_Thread` by calling `FORM_REQUEST(X)` macro. Each bit in `g_FORM_Requests` is an execution request flag for a separate task. The execution order of these tasks does not matter.

Am I right in assuming that it would work correctly? If not, where is the problem?

**EDIT 1:**

The `volatile` keyword makes sure that at the end of `SERVER_Thread` the `g_FORM_Requests` is read again before XORing it with `Snapshot`. This means if `FORM_REQUEST()` is interrupted in the middle of changing `g_FORM_Requests`, it would not cause erroneous behavior, because only the bits that are set in `Snapshot` will be removed from it.

The question is NOT if we can use volatile keyword as a barrier. I'm utilizing the fact that one of my threads only converts zeros to ones, and the other thread converts ones to zeros. Hence the `g_FORM_Requests` variable itself acts as a lock, and partial execution of the Critical Section in each thread is not problematic...

Comment: I know, It's not atomic. But I don't think that would cause a problem... Volatile is there to make sure at the end of SERVER_Thread, the g_FORM_Requests is read again before performing XOR.

Comment: This example is not using volatile keyword as a barrier. I'm using the fact that one one of my threads only converts zeros to ones, and the other thread converts ones to zeros.

Comment: I read the linked post, and I still don't get it why did you close this question? It's not a duplicate...

Comment: The problem isn't visibility, it's ordering. There is nothing to guarantee the xor will occur **after** the call to Execute.

Comment: Execute only uses the snapshot. The g_FORM_Requests is not accessed...

Comment: The xor is a read-modify-write, i.e., three distinct operations. Consider this: thread one enters the assign block, but before it can write, thread two loads Snapshot with zero. The xor loads gForm (still zero) and xors it with Snap resulting in zero. Now thread one finally assigns the request to gForm in thread one, only to be immediately overwritten by zero in thread two.

Comment: You are right. Thank you... :)

Comment: @JohnQ.: Another possible duplicate target: [Can `num++` be atomic for 'int num'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num/39396999#39396999).  That explains exactly why read-modify-write ops aren't atomic "by default", unlike separate stores and loads, even if they happen to compile to a single memory-destination x86 instruction.  (The C memory model still disallows concurrent write+read of non-atomic variables, of course, and provides `memory_order_relaxed` for when you need atomicity but not ordering).